# Uneven cassandra load

Tags: cassandra

I have a 10 node ring & all the nodes seem to share about the same amount of data except one is considerably less does anyone have ideas?

```
Rack        Status State   Load            Owns                Token 
                                                               153127065114422308558518573344295695155
rack1       Up     Normal  17.92 GB        10.00%              0                                        
rack1       Up     Normal  14.31 GB        10.00%              17014118346046923173168730371588410572 
rack1       Up     Normal  41.42 KB        10.00%              34028236692093846346337460743176821145
rack1       Up     Normal  17.68 GB        10.00%              51042355038140769519506191114765231718
rack1       Up     Normal  18.65 GB        10.00%              68056473384187692692674921486353642291
rack1       Up     Normal  18.33 GB        10.00%              102084710076281539039012382229530463436 
rack1       Up     Normal  17.44 GB        10.00%              119098828422328462212181112601118874009
rack1       Up     Normal  17.71 GB        10.00%              136112946768375385385349842972707284582 
rack1       Up     Normal  17.37 GB        10.00%              153127065114422308558518573344295695155
```

Comment: you have a total of 90% of data in this ring, is this the full output of the nodetool's ring command?

Answer (score 0):

"Owns" just covers the "primary range" for a node, which is the range counter-clockwise from that node until the next node.
Token for a node determines what data in a whole range that node would maintain. Its possible that the data range in which the node's token lie makes it own on few KB of data, I would suggest running nodetool repair and then run nodetool ring to see the status.
One more thing, whats your RF?